# Voip Voice Call using Twilio in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, twilio-click-to-call

I have to implement app to app call for my xamarin forms app. i have been looking since couple of days but i couldn't find any github file. after that i have found one github file but i am getting error while run in visual studio 2017(https://github.com/twilio/TwilioChatXamarinBindings), Please help you resolve this error, Here i have pasted below error.

Error:

Error       The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Twilio.Chat.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Twilio.Chat.Android.dll'
Error   CS0305  Using the generic type 'CallbackListener' requires 1 type arguments  Twilio.Chat.Android 
Error   CS0115  'CallbackListener.OnSuccess(Object)': no suitable method found to override   Twilio.Chat.Android 
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'InternalPaginator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Note: One more think, I would like know, is it possible to implement app to app voip voice call using twilio like whatsapp